# Rewriting URL does not automatically log me in

Tags: url-rewriting

I've installed my blog at `www.mysite.com/blog`

I want to re-write the URL to take out the `blog` part so you can access it at `www.mysite.com`

I added a rewrite rule in `.htaccess` file, but I noticed that when I go to the rewritten URL, I am not logged into my account; I would have to go through the original `/blog` to be logged in.

What is the problem here and how can I solve it?

Comment: Did you follow all the steps on [Giving WordPress its own directory](http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory), or did you just add the rewrite rules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wordpress has support for installing in a different directory to your desired home directory.

Have a read of the two bullet points near the top of this page: http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL

Comment: Changing the home URL worked for me.

Comment: Glad it worked out!